# c# Background thread gets an error when run in UserControl

Tags: c#, multithreading, background, user-controls

Right now in my UserControl, I have a button click event that starts a thread. I've since moved on from using Abort(), and trying to convert my thread to a background process so that they shut down when I close the parent form. My code is:

```
public Thread t;
private void btnInitiate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UDPListener myListiner = new UDPListener(this);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t = new Thread(() => myListiner.SpreadValue(myCurrentPort, firstTicker, secondTicker, myBeta));
        t.Start();
    }
```

But when I run the application, I get an error from `t.IsBackground=true` where it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I'm wondering where I am going wrong in this case.

Comment: After you start the Task, your method is done but the task is still running myListiner falls out of scope. Create the listener within the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change row order in your code:

```
...
t = new Thread(() => myListiner.SpreadValue(myCurrentPort, firstTicker, secondTicker, myBeta));
t.IsBackground = true;
...
```

Because you need to instantiate your thread and only then use it.